# Find the radius of the circle given the length of arc and chord

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

My dad asked me this seemingly simple problem:

> Suppose you have a (thin) piece of wood in the shape of a circular arc. You can measure the curved length of the wood, $\ell_1$, as well as the shortest distance between the two end points, $\ell_2$.
>
> [image]
>
> What is the radius of the original circle, in terms of $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$?

It feels like it should have a simple solution, but if my reasoning is correct, we have the equations $$\begin{cases}\ell_1 = r\theta\\\ell_2=2r\sin(\frac\theta2),\end{cases}$$
and it doesn't seem trivial to isolate $r$.

If we allow ourselves to make use of the inverse of the $\operatorname{sinc}(x)=\frac{\sin x}x$ function (we can restrict $x$ to $[0,\pi)$ for our purposes), by considering $\ell_2/\ell_1$, we obtain
$$r = \frac{\ell_1}{2\operatorname{sinc}^{-1}({\ell_2}/{\ell_1})}$$
which I guess is some sort of an answer. Can we do better? Perhaps some kind of integral representation?

Comment: Your **sinc** formula seems to be as simple as you can get. How would an integral be any better?

Comment: Well I can approximate an integral with straightforward algorithms, I don't know how to invert $\operatorname{sinc}$ easily.

Comment: For very nice sinc inverse there is [MSE question 2175174](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2175174) "Inverse Sinc Approximation".